# How to use GCP compute API as current user?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

I have a script which lists compute engine resources and am using it by calling the compute method with Python. So far I’ve been running it from a VM so it used the VM service account to run.
How could I run it as my own user account? What I mean by that is if I were to run the script locally from an IDE how could I have it log in as the current user?
My current log-in looks something like this:

> from googleapiclient import discovery
> service = discovery.build(‘compute’, ‘v1’, credentials=None)

Comment: Research Google Cloud ADC (Application Default Credentials). For your code you should use a service account: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production You can also setup default credentials with `gcloud auth application-default login` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

Answer (score 1):

On the VM, you can perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` to create files, with your own credential, in the well-known location.

The problem is: the metadata server are used before the well-known location file with the Google Cloud client libraries. The trick is to define the `GOOGLE_APLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to your credentials file; this env var is the first one checked and used if present.

On a Linux VM, you can find them here

```
~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

*However, the fact to use your own credential on a VM, is strange and lead me to think that your design isn't correct. You are playing with secrets! Be careful!*